# EditText in listview gets duplicated

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-viewholder, android-textwatcher

I know this question is asked many times before and followed them and I am up to the mark to a great extent with only one problem left.I was able to solve the duplicating issue by adding **textwatcher** and using **hashmap** to store value but problem that is left is that the value of original edit text is also gone when I scroll back to it. By this I mean that if I type something in say first `EditText` and then scroll down, that value doesn't get repeated anywhere but the value of `EditText` in which I typed is also gone. Here is my code.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_planmanobra_row, parent, false);
            holder.periodo_zafra = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.periodo_zafra);
            holder.CODIGO_FINCA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CODIGO_FINCA);
            //holder.NOMBRE_FINCA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NOMBRE_FINCA);
            holder.MES = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MES);
            holder.CLAVE = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CLAVE);
            holder.NOMBRE_CLAVE = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NOMBRE_CLAVE);
            holder.CODIGO_ESTANDAR = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CODIGO_ESTANDAR);
            holder.NOMBRE_ESTANDAR_MO = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NOMBRE_ESTANDAR_MO);
            holder.CANTIDAD_ESTANDAR = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CANTIDAD_ESTANDAR);
            holder.VALOR_UNITARIO = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.VALOR_UNITARIO);
            holder.VALOR_TOTAL = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.VALOR_TOTAL);
            holder.EJECUTA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EJECUTA);
            holder.btn_submit= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
            holder.btn_submit.setText("Enviar");
            holder.Cantidad= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_cantidad);
            holder.Cantidad_empleados= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Cantidad_empleados);
            holder.checkbox= (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.periodo_zafra.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getPERIODO_ZAFRA());
        holder.CODIGO_FINCA.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getCODIGO_FINCA());
       // holder.NOMBRE_FINCA.setText(planiBeanArrayList.get(position).getNOMBRE_FINCA());
        holder.MES.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getMES());
        holder.CLAVE.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getCLAVE());
        holder.NOMBRE_CLAVE.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getNOMBRE_CLAVE());
        holder.CODIGO_ESTANDAR.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getCODIGO_ESTANDAR());
        holder.NOMBRE_ESTANDAR_MO.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getNOMBRE_ESTANDAR_MO());
        holder.CANTIDAD_ESTANDAR.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getCANTIDAD_ESTANDAR());
        holder.VALOR_UNITARIO.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getVALOR_UNITARIO());
        holder.VALOR_TOTAL.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getVALOR_TOTAL());
        holder.EJECUTA.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getEJECUTA());
        holder.Cantidad.setText(editTextList.get(position));
        holder.Cantidad.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                editTextList.put(position,charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        holder.btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

**Cantidad** is the edit text

Comment: Refer here this might give u some help  http://coderzpassion.com/android-custom-listview-with-edittext/

Comment: what happens is, the model (data holder, in ur case `planmanobraBeanArrayList`) have certain value for attribute X, when `getView()` is called it render/init/reuse views to create proper list for you, reading data from the model, in this case it will be the data already in the model, not the one entered (altered) in the editText, what you need to do is to update the model data once the editText is changed, so next time this item is rendered, it will populate using new data in model

Comment: @Yazan so you mean to say that in textwatcher I should set the value again in planmanobraBeanArrayList?

Comment: yup, it could be a way, the idea is to capture updated values from EditText(s) and update the corresponding value of that item in the data-list or array.

Comment: ok I will try that

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it working using Focus Change Listener and adding one more parameter to the existing arraylist. Using another list or Hashmap didn't worked for me. So as suggested by **Yazan** I added it in my arraylist and is working now. Here is the code what I have now

```
 holder.Cantidad.setText(planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).getEditext());
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.Cantidad.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus)
                {
                    if (!finalHolder.Cantidad.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).setEditext(finalHolder.Cantidad.getText().toString());
                    }else {
                        planmanobraBeanArrayList.get(position).setEditext("");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Thanks for everyone help